# nginx problem after install certbot, does not redirect requests

Tags: python, nginx, certbot

nginx server does not redirect to my apps after install SSL certificates with certbot. i've tried alot of solutions posted in differents foros, but they don't worked to me.

here is my `.conf` in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`

```
# FastAPI app

upstream backend {
   127.0.0.1:8080
}

# Django app

upstream app {
   127.0.0.1:8081
}


server {
    server_name my.appdomain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }


    location /app/ {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

        }
    
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.api.directoryfox.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/img.api.directoryfox.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = my.appdomain.com) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name my.appdomain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

before installing certbot, the server worked fine. I don't know what to do, any help please?

Comment: What error do you get? 404 Page not found?

Comment: exceeded timeout, does not redirects to apps, without certbot it works fine. thanks for your help @anemyte, let me know if need more information.

Comment: Where do you run it? Could it be a cloud virtual machine by any chance?

Comment: it's running in a jetson nano

Comment: I thinks it's a firewall problem, check that 443 is open.

Comment: @anemyte thank you !! it lead me to solution, it was my router configuration that does not redirect 443 port requests. thanks for your help again.